# Core segmentation on .so library in C++

Tags: c++, coredump

The program works fine until you use a determinated size for the array called tsp ,then it gives a segmentation fault.

```
std::cout<<"point1"<<std::endl;
vector< pair< int, float > > valores ;
std::cout<<"point2"<<std::endl;
cargar_vector_valores(valores, defenses); 
std::cout<<"point3"<<std::endl;             
unsigned int cost = 0;
std::cout<<"point4"<<std::endl;
//copiar lista de defenses a vector
vector<Defense*> copia_defenses;
std::cout<<"point5"<<std::endl;
for(std::list<Defense*>::iterator it=++defenses.begin();it != defenses.end();it++){
    copia_defenses.push_back((*it));
}
std::cout<<"point6"<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"defenses.size()-1="<<defenses.size()-1<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"cols = "<<ases+1<<std::endl;
int rows=defenses.size()-1;
int cols=ases+1;
int tsp [rows][cols];
std::cout<<"point7"<<std::endl;
selectedIDs.push_back((*defenses.begin())->id);
std::cout<<"point8"<<std::endl;
ases-=(*defenses.begin())->cost;
std::cout<<"point9"<<std::endl;
```

And this is the out of the program

```
point1
point2
point3
point4
point5
point6
defenses.size()-1=165
cols = 12769
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

A core dumped when I create a array..I don't know what's the problem.

Comment: Where is `ases` defined?

Comment: First a technicality, [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) are not a C++ feature, it's an extension of the compiler you're using. Secondly you're trying to allocate over 8 MB on the stack. The default stack for a Linux process is exactly 8MB, so with all other variables you have, call frames, and everything else that's stored on the stack, you're way over limit.

Comment: Finally, is there a reason you're not using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)?

Comment: I 've used std::vector and now works perfect thank you all

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, you are trying to allocate too much memory on the stack. 165*12769 = 2106885 integers if we consider int are 32 bits on your systems, we get 8230 KiB which is over the stack size on Linux (usually 8192 KiB, you can verify with the shell command $ulimit -s). Considering the others variables and everything in the program you are passed that limit. You should instead allocate memory on the heap, either with a new or using an std structure like a std::vector.

Also, as pointed out by Joachim Pileborg,

```
int tsp [rows][cols];
```

are not standard C++ since your rows and cols are not determined at compile-time. Your compiler is using the [variable-length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) extension to make it works but this will not work on all compilers so it make be something you want to avoid.